# AWS EC2 Instance: SSH instance Operation timed out when connectiong through Mac

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ec2-ami

I launched Amazon Linux instance and I am using a default security group with following settings:

```
Type:All traffic
Protocol:All
Port Range:All
```

But when connecting through ssh from my Mac I get Operation Timed Out message:

```
ssh -i "<key in double quotes>" ec2-user@<>.amazonaws.com
```

result in

```
ssh: connect to host <>.amazonaws.com port 22: Operation timed out
```

I am not sure what could be the reason. Can someone please help?

Comment: Have you _ever_ managed to SSH into an EC2 instance from the same network? Can you SSH into an instance that is in a different VPC/Subnet?

Answer (score 2):

A time-out normally indicates there is **no network connectivity** to the remote computer. A simple rule-of-thumb is:

- If the error comes back immediately, then the SSH request has been rejected by the remote computer
- If the error takes some time to come back (eg 5+ seconds), then it never reached the remote computer

Some potential causes:

- Something else is blocking the access, such as a **corporate firewall**. Try from a different network (eg home, work, tether via your phone) to try and diagnose this situation.
- The instance might be in a **private subnet**
- The instance might be in a **subnet that is incorrectly configured** (eg not routing to an Internet Gateway to make a 'Public' subnet)